# html5 website load table

Tags: javascript, html

Hi all i'm not too sure if i'm asking the question correctly as this is my first time to code. If anyone could point me to the right direction of learning and asking the right question would be awesome.

So i'm trying to write a repair service website that when client select a brand say "HP", a table of hp laptop model will show up as options. But if the client select "Apple", the laptop model at the table will be replaced by apple laptop models.

```
    <div class ="container" id="repair">
    <ul class="brand">
    <li data-id="1" class>Apple</li>
    <li data-id="2" class>Lenovo</li>
    <li data-id="3" class>Dell</li>
    <li data-id="4" class>HP</li>
    </ul><!-- end of brand -->

    <div class ="title">Model</div>
    <ul id="model" class="model">
    <li data-id="11" data-name="MacBook Air">MacBook Air</li>
    <li data-id="12" data-name="MacBook Pro">MacBook Pro</li>
    <li data-id="13" data-name="MacBook">MacBook</li>
    <li data-id="21" data-name="Lenovo X260">Lenovo X260</li>
    <li data-id="22" data-name="Lenovo X270">Lenovo X270</li>
    <li data-id="23" data-name="Lenovo X280">Lenovo X280</li>
    <li data-id="31" data-name="Dell Latitude 1400">Dell Latitude 1400</li>
    </ul> <!--end of table-->
</div>
```

So my question is, how can I code it so when data-id 1 is selected, only data-id 11, 12,13 show up and none of the others?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Good job on making a detailed question like this, it really helps us when trying to help you.

Comment: Well first, you can't "select" `li` elements. Your brand list should be a `select`. Then, you add a "change" event handler to that `select` that fires a callback function that hides/shows the appropriate content of the bulleted list. But, you have to make an effort to do this first.

Comment: @Isuckatthis do you expect a click on those li elements or you are expecting a dropdown list here?

Comment: Thank you @IsaacCorbrey and @ ScottMarcus for the quick reply.

my understanding is with select there'll be a dropdown box and select the brands. 

<select>
  <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="Dell">Dell</option>
  <option value="Lenovo">Lenovo</option>
  <option value="HP">HP</option>
</select>
What i'm trying to do is to have them all show up, if i click on the Apple, then a table will generate out with MacBook Air, MacBook Pro and MacBook.

Comment: That's correct about the `select`. But, you can style the `select` so that all the options are visible from the start. Also, the `option` elements don't need a `value` specified for them if you want their values to be the same as their content, so just `<option>Volvo</option>` is fine, for example.

Comment: See *[this](https://jsfiddle.net/796ex7cp/4/)* for an example of using a select that is expanded.

Comment: thank you @ScottMarcus. I've been reading https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_value.asp
but it didn't say anything about option and option value. Can you direct me to somewhere so i can get a better understand? cheers

Comment: W3 Schools is widely known to have outdated, incomplete or flat out incorrect information. Don't use it. Instead use *[The Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org)* for just about any question relating to HTML, CSS, JavaScript and more. Specifically, [here is the link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) to using the `select`.

Comment: And, [here is the link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) for the `option` element. In the section on the `value`, it says ***"If this attribute is omitted, the value is taken from the text content of the option element."***

Comment: And, actually the W3 Schools page you linked to does say ***Note: If the value attribute is not specified, the content will be passed as a value instead.***

Answer (score 0):

You can check for `charAt(0)` of `data-id` for the `model` list. Then show them if they match. Considering that you click the `li` elements for the `brand`

```js
$('.brand li').click(function(){
  var dataId = $(this).data('id').toString();
  $('#model li').hide();
  $('#model li').each(function(){
    if($(this).data('id').toString().charAt(0) === dataId){
      $(this).show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#model li{
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class ="container" id="repair">
    <ul class="brand">
      <li data-id="1" class>Apple</li>
      <li data-id="2" class>Lenovo</li>
      <li data-id="3" class>Dell</li>
      <li data-id="4" class>HP</li>
    </ul><!-- end of brand -->

    <div class ="title">Model</div>
      <ul id="model" class="model">
        <li data-id="11" data-name="MacBook Air">MacBook Air</li>
        <li data-id="12" data-name="MacBook Pro">MacBook Pro</li>
        <li data-id="13" data-name="MacBook">MacBook</li>
        <li data-id="21" data-name="Lenovo X260">Lenovo X260</li>
        <li data-id="22" data-name="Lenovo X270">Lenovo X270</li>
        <li data-id="23" data-name="Lenovo X280">Lenovo X280</li>
        <li data-id="31" data-name="Dell Latitude 1400">Dell Latitude 1400</li>
      </ul> <!--end of table-->
</div>
```

Comment: With your rep, one would think that you would know not to answer questions that do not not even have an attempt at a solution in them.

Comment: @ScottMarcus since OP is newbie I answered this to make him know how he can achieve this.

Comment: Yeah. That's the point. If we just provide all the newbies with working code, it will just attract more newbies asking poor questions that shouldn't be answered. We're not a code writing service. The correct thing to do with a question like this is direct the OP to Google or some learning resource, not just write up a solution.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I respect your reply. I will note that. Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much@AnkitAgarwal for your solution. I'm still a bit confused with the meaning of html and javascript, so with html, it's really  to do with the structure and content, and with javascript, it is to do with what to show, what to hide?

Comment: @Isuckatthis HTML is for structure, content and semantics. CSS is for presentation and JavaScript is for behavior.

Comment: @Isuckatthis I will recommend you to learn some basics on this before you actually post a question directly here in SO.

Answer (score 0):

We can store all of the brands and items as a JSON object, like so:

```
"Products": [
    "Apple": {
        "MacBook",
        "MacBook Air",
        "MacBook Pro"
    },
    "HP": {
        "..."
    },
    ...
]
```

We can then use this in a JavaScript file to externally modify the contents of the list for whatever is selected. For the selection I would use the [`<input>` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp).

Comment: @ScottMarcus Man, you are just all over this thread, aren't you? My answer is meant to guide OP towards a solution. As you said under the other answer, we are not a code writing service. I gave OP examples of how to organize his data, an important part of the process. I also gave him a reference to a site to help him figure out how to use said data. I understand that you don't want suboptimal questions on the site, but sometimes the new people just don't know how to ask what they want to ask. Please be more mindful in the future.

Comment: Yes, I am a contributing member of the Stack Overflow community. Your desire to help is great, but the way to do that here would be to post a comment and perhaps a link to a JS Fiddle if you need to show code. Please understand that what you've posted is not an answer and so it shouldn't have been posted as one. Also, you must understand that if we "reward" poor questions with answers, we will just attract more poor questions....

Comment: ...That's why we have [guidelines on this stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) (note the section on *Answer well asked questions* where it says *Not all questions can or should be answered here.*) Please be mindful of this in the future.

Comment: thank you for your efforts.

so I've been trying to use the onclick function and to load the stored name on to html through the json file i have,  but what i get when i clicked on "iphone" is undefined. I'm not too sure where did i do wrong.

https://jsfiddle.net/796ex7cp/11/

And here's my json file
https://api.myjson.com/bins/rqqbb

Comment: @Isuckatthis You're calling `iPhone()` without parameters, but you declared it with a parameter `iPhone(phone)`

Comment: @Isuckatthis Also, your JSON and the data you are referencing in your JavaScript does not match.